# Mediaelement js is not playing mp3 in IE

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

This is my first post here, so forgive me if i don't follow all the unwritten laws here :)

I am using mediaelement.js for playing mp3 files. It works great in all the browsers i have tested, except from IE11. I get an errer in my browser saying "Invalid source". The soundfiles i use are loaded from a database, and a typical URL for a file would be /filestreamer?fileId=2342342

As You can see, there is no file extension in the URL. I wonder if this is what causes the problem in IE? Is there anyone who can confirm if that is or is not the case?

Here's the code i use: fileUrl will be like /filestreamer?fileId=2342342

```
$j("#soundPlayer").append('<audio id="player1" width="100%" poster="poster.jpg" controls="controls" autoplay="true" preload="none"><source type="audio/mp3" src="'+fileUrl+'" /><object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/adapt-it/scripts/jquery/johndyer-mediaelement/build/flashmediaelement.swf"><param name="movie" value="/adapt-it/scripts/jquery/johndyer-mediaelement/build/flashmediaelement.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file='+fileUrl+'" /><img src="myvideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" /></object></audio>');
```

Kindly regards,
Lars

Comment: EDIT: I just added a code example, showing how i put the player into the page.

Comment: What is the source of the audio? There's an issue with IE10+ and Shoutcast returning a response IE doesn't accept.

Comment: The source is, for example http://localhost:8080/somepath/filestreamer?fileId=23452345235

Comment: Are you sendind the correct mimetype? You sure it is in the edge mode (not compatibility view)?

Comment: @VitorCanova: Checking in dev-console in IE11 i see the that the type is: application/octet-stream. I am not sure if this is what it should be or not. And yes, I am not in compatibility mode.

Comment: This kind o mimetype looks generic. I think the browser can be avoiding play this because it is waiting something like "audio/mpeg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the mime-type, or content-type if you wish. I managed after some debugging to set it to "audio/mp3" and everything worked like a charm. Thanks for all help :)